# Is there a nice way to simplify $ \frac{\sin x \theta}{\sin \theta}-\frac{\cos x \theta}{\cos \theta}=x-1 $ to get solutions?

Tags: trigonometry

Find all the
real solutions of $x$ such that
$$
\frac{\sin x \theta}{\sin \theta}-\frac{\cos x \theta}{\cos \theta}=x-1
$$
holds for all $\theta$ which are not integral multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ i tried at first to solve using sin2a and sin(a-b) identities but after that equation looks unsolvable , but i got a trivial sol of x =1 by observing the expression

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: $x=1$ is a solution.

Comment: The solutions are exactly $x=-1,1,3$.

Comment: @GEdgar Please refrain from sending the "answer" to a problem with no context

Comment: @Blue really sry i forgot to share my method but ig i did that in my previous questions . Again really sry

Answer (score 3):

Get the fractions under a common denominator, then use
$$\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)=\sin(a-b)$$
On the numerator, and
$$2\sin(a)\cos(a)=\sin(2a)$$
On the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Taking up the problem where @TheBestMagician leaves off, we get
$$
\frac{\sin (\theta (x-1))}{\sin 2\theta}=\frac{x-1}{2}.
$$
Taking one derivative with respect to $\theta$ gives
$$
(x-1)\cos (\theta(x-1)) \sin 2\theta=\sin (\theta (x-1))(2\cos 2\theta)
$$
giving
$$
\frac{x-1}{2} \tan 2\theta=\tan (\theta(x-1)).
$$
Taking another derivative w.r.t. $\theta$,
$$
(x-1) \sec^2 2\theta = (x-1)\sec^2(\theta(x-1)).
$$
Then either $x=1$ or
$$
\sec 2\theta =\pm \sec (\theta(x-1)).
$$
This should be valid for $\theta=0,$ forcing
$$
\sec 2\theta=\sec(\theta(x-1)),$$
leading to the answer given by @GEdgar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fast way to solve the problem.

If $$\frac{\sin (x \theta)}{\sin (\theta)}-\frac{\cos (x \theta)}{\cos (\theta)}=x-1\tag 1$$ that is to say
$$(1-x) \sin (2\theta) -2\sin ((1- x)\theta)=0\tag 2$$ holds for all $\theta$, then it must hold for very small values of $\theta$.

Expanding the lhs as a series around $\theta=0$, it write
$$(1-x) \sin (2\theta) -2\sin ((1- x)\theta)=-\frac{1}{6} \theta^3 \left(x^3-3 x^2-x+3\right)+O\left(\theta^5\right)$$ So the values of $x$ are the solutions of
$$x^3-3 x^2-x+3=(x-3) (x-1) (x+1)=0$$

**Remark**

We could even do it using $(1)$ only since
$$\frac{\sin (x \theta)}{\sin (\theta)}=x+\frac{1}{6} \theta ^2 \left(x-x^3\right)+\frac{1}{360} \theta ^4 \left(3 x^5-10
   x^3+7 x\right)+O\left(\theta ^6\right)$$
$$\frac{\cos (x \theta)}{\cos (\theta)}=1+\theta ^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24} \theta ^4
   \left(x^4-6 x^2+5\right)+O\left(\theta ^6\right)$$
$$\frac{\sin (x \theta)}{\sin (\theta)}-\frac{\cos (x \theta)}{\cos (\theta)}=(x-1)-\frac{1}{6} \theta ^2 ((x-3) (x-1) (x+1))+O\left(\theta ^4\right)$$

Comment: Nice approach .

Comment: (+1) I think you mean $\theta$ not $t.$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can u tell how u got this ? "$$\frac{\sin (x \theta)}{\sin (\theta)}=x+\frac{1}{6} \theta ^2 \left(x-x^3\right)+\frac{1}{360} \theta ^4 \left(3 x^5-10
   x^3+7 x\right)+O\left(\theta ^6\right)$$"

Comment: @Paracetamol. Use the series expansions for the sine function and then long division.

Comment: Hmm that is pretty lengthy by long division but still got a idea , by first method Expanding the lhs can u a bit detail ur steps to get to the final -1/6 theta^3..+ O(theta^5) one ? And why does that theta ^5 term doesnt matter?